# React and react-chartjs-2, Line chart not displaying data from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, charts, react-chartjs

I am trying to render a Line chart using react-chartjs-2. Right now it works fine when I pass in static props to the Line Component. But, when I fetch data from an API, set it to a variable, then pass that variable as the prop. My Line Component is not re-rendering with the new data.

I am logging the props being passed into the Line Component and I can see it first arrives as null and then I receive the good data from the API. So it looks like the Line Component is not re-rendering after receiving the props? I am probably doing this wrong. Please help.

```
import React from "react";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";

export default class ExpenseChart extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            marketData: [100, 200, 300],
            chartData: {
                labels: this.props.monthNames,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(142, 243, 197, 0.5)",
                        pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                        pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
                        pointStyle: "circle",
                        label: "Monthly Expenses",
                        borderColor: "#2be1d8",
                        borderWidth: 3,
                        borderJoinStyle: "round",
                        lineTension: 0.3,
                        fontColor: "#fff",
                        hitRadius: 5,
                        hoverRadius: 8,
                        radius: 4,
                        data: this.props.monthExpenses
                    },
                ],
            },
        };
    }

    render() {
        console.log("why no names", this.props.monthNames)
        return (
            <div className="expenseChart">
                <h2 className="expenseChart__name">{this.props.graphname}</h2>
                 <Line
                    data={this.state.chartData}
                    options={{
                        maintainAspectRatio: false,
                        responsive: true,
                        aspectRatio: 3,
                        scales: {
                            yAxes: [
                                {
                                    ticks: {
                                        display: false,
                                    },
                                },
                            ],
                        },
                        layout: {
                            padding: {
                                right: 10,
                            },
                        },
                    }}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And then the parent component is connected to a redux store and it looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ExpenseChart from "../elements/ExpenseChart";
import { fetchExpenses } from '../../actions/index';

class Dashboard extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(fetchExpenses());
    }

    render() {
        let labels = this.props.months && this.props.months;

        return (
            <main className="dashboard">
                <ExpenseChart
                    monthNames={labels}
                    monthExpenses={["123", "123", "12312", "12341", "231231", "1231", "1231"]}
                    // I am receiving monthExpenses props into the ExpenseChart component
                    // but not monthNames
                />
            </main>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth: state.app.auth,
    months: state.app.months,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Dashboard);
```

I've done something similar before, fetching data from an API and passing it as props to the Line Component. But only difference is I am using redux here. And obviously, this time the Line Component is not receiving the good data.

Comment: Are you getting the API response in n/w tab?

Comment: i didn't use this library but many diagrams expect parent and/or itself to have height and width, please check that maybe it can be a problem

Comment: @nithin Yes I am getting the API response and the data. It just will not update my chartjs Line component.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be on this `componentDidMount` code.

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(fetchExpenses());
    }
```

As per docs on [dispatch](https://redux.js.org/api/store#dispatchaction)

> action (Object†): A plain object describing the change that makes
>   sense for your application. Actions are the only way to get data into
>   the store, so any data, whether from the UI events, network callbacks,
>   or other sources such as WebSockets needs to eventually be dispatched
>   as actions. Actions must have a type field that indicates the type of
>   action being performed. Types can be defined as constants and imported
>   from another module. It's better to use strings for type than Symbols
>   because strings are serializable. Other than type, the structure of an
>   action object is really up to you. If you're interested, check out
>   Flux Standard Action for recommendations on how actions could be
>   constructed.

Here `fetchExpenses` might be returning a promise and in that case you might need

```
fetchExpenses().then(apiRes => dipatch({type: "ACTION_TYPE": payload: apiRes}))
```

Another approach can be to use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)

Comment: I am using redux-thunk for my async actions to fetch the data. `fetchExpenses()` is an action that fetches the data from an API. I then replace the redux store with the new data. From my original post, I am pulling the months data `this.props.months` and passing it as props to the `ExpenseChart` component. But it will not receive the props. At least, it won't update once it receives it, since it is an async data fetch.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved this just by checking if the data I was receiving was not null before passing it as props. Which is what I thought this line would do `let labels = this.props.months && this.props.months;`

```
<main className="dashboard">
    { this.props.months != null ? <ExpenseChart monthNames={labels}/> : ''; }
</main>
```